# Pull text value from clickable filter option

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

On the product category page of an e-commerce site there are product filters. With these filters a visitor can quickly change the products that are visible. 
The filters can be used in two ways. There is a checkbox you can click on and you can click on the value. The outcome of each is the same. Here is a screenshot of how it looks like: http://prntscr.com/qiu5rx.

Now I want to retrieve the value / label of what is being clicked on. I have no idea with my limited JavaScript skills how to do this.
The end goal is to have this value send to Google Analytics. This isn't the problem because I can get this done through Google Tag Manager. Right now it's about retrieving the label or value of the filter.

Below you can see the HTML of 1 filter option.

```html
<li class="woof_term_1251 ">
  <div class="icheckbox_square-green checked" style="position: relative;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="woof_1251_5e0f1894f1ef2" class="woof_checkbox_term woof_checkbox_term_1251" data-tax="pa_series" name="200" data-term-id="1251" value="1251" checked="checked" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
    <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins>
  </div>
  <label class="woof_checkbox_label woof_checkbox_label_selected" for="woof_1251_5e0f1894f1ef2">Label I want to pull</label>
  <input type="hidden" value="Value I want to pull" data-anchor="woof_n_pa_series_-200">
</li>
```

Can someone please help me with guiding in the right direction? I would like to solve this with JavaScript or Jquery.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to get the value of the checkbox or the text of the label?

Comment: I would like to obtain the text of the label

Answer (score 0):

i have added class to all filterable checkboxes.
using this class i too html collection in my javascript and attached handlers on check change.
and then logging all checked fitlers.

here is the demo, look for console logs.
https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-mirzakhani-ignxp

Answer (score 0):

> I want to obtain the text of the label

To do this hook to the `change` event of the `checkbox`, then you can traverse the DOM to retrieve the `text()` from the sibling `label` using `closest()` and `find()`:

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  var labelText = $(this).closest('li').find('label').text();
  console.log(labelText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="woof_term_1251 ">
    <div class="icheckbox_square-green checked" style="position: relative;">
      <input type="checkbox" id="woof_1251_5e0f1894f1ef2" class="woof_checkbox_term woof_checkbox_term_1251" data-tax="pa_series" name="200" data-term-id="1251" value="1251" checked="checked" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
      <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins>
    </div>
    <label class="woof_checkbox_label woof_checkbox_label_selected" for="woof_1251_5e0f1894f1ef2">Label I want to pull</label>
    <input type="hidden" value="Value I want to pull" data-anchor="woof_n_pa_series_-200">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello Rory, thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I tried modifying the selector and the change event to click but there were no results.
I tested on a random page if jQuery was working and a click event + an alert was working.

As soon as I add your code through the console it displays a list of all the checkboxes: http://prntscr.com/qsp355. However as soon as I test it nothing is happening. Can you please push me in the right direction how to solve this?